# Trigger probe-request on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, wifi, probe

I am looking for way to trigger `Wifi rediscover` on iPhone.

I would like to imitate going into the Wifi Settings but actually without doing this.
Just wondering if there is any method in `SystemConfiguration.framework` or in `CFNetwork.framework` which could do this happen?

Of course turning Wifi off and on via `SBWiFiManager` is not the way, it is not going to be accepted by Apple anyway.

Or maybe there are other frames other than probe that can propagate somehow without being actually connected to the Wifi network.

Cheers

Comment: check the Rechability class.

Comment: We're you able to solve this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't found any way to actually do it with the Apple approval.